# Limit the number of registrations one email account can make using php

Tags: php, registration

I am trying to build a php registration form that collects all the usual name, surname, email but I'm not sure how to stop multiple registrations using the same e-mail address or username. How do I go about such a thing?

Comment: if (another user has the same e-mail) { echo "some other user has registered with this e-mail, choose another" }. Moreover, enforce the check on the DB also via a unique key

Comment: Use the email address as a unique index in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the database before inserting the record for duplicate email or login names.
(make sure to use parameterized queries, this is just an illustration of the SQL)

```
SELECT emailaddress, username FROM [mytable] WHERE emailaddress = 'abc@123.com' OR username = 'dude smith'
```

If this returns any records then do not run the insert and return a message that a user with that email address or username exists and you can offer to return them to the login page to use that login.

Note: A duplicate email is a good indication that this is the same person, but a duplicate username is NOT a good indication this is the same person. I would treat each issue separately.